# Can't run systemd inside docker container on specific host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, systemd

I'm migrating a containerized deployment from a Ubuntu 20.04 host to a Ubuntu 22.04 one. The container runs systemd, and it works fine in the 20.04 machine:

```
$ docker run -i -d --name test-cvmfs-publisher-hs --rm --tmpfs /run:rw --tmpfs /tmp:rw --device /dev/fuse --volume "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro" --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined cvmfs-stratum0_new
432f62194e87996de7b0ee483b52f1306c13ebaf1a0065478032202fcd937fc1
$ docker exec -it test-cvmfs-publisher-hs bash
[root@432f62194e87 /]# systemctl status
● 432f62194e87
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Sat 2024-02-10 14:17:13 UTC; 7s ago
   CGroup: /docker/432f62194e87996de7b0ee483b52f1306c13ebaf1a0065478032202fcd937fc1
           ├─  1 /usr/sbin/init
           ├─ 88 bash
           ├─104 systemctl status
           ├─105 more
           └─system.slice
             ├─systemd-journald.service
             │ └─18 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
             ├─crond.service
             │ └─49 /usr/sbin/crond -n
             ├─httpd.service
             │ ├─66 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─70 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─71 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─72 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ ├─73 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             │ └─74 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─dbus.service
             │ └─41 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
             ├─cvmfs-gateway.service
             │ └─60 /usr/bin/cvmfs_gateway
             └─systemd-logind.service
               └─37 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
```

Using the same image on the 22.04 host I get this:

```
$ docker run -i -d --name test-cvmfs-publisher-hs --rm --tmpfs /run:rw --tmpfs /tmp:rw --device /dev/fuse --volume "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro" --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor:unconfined cvmfs-stratum0_new
127ed5f4833f41b7cb20e95b8752678a1a8195848358814ecbd4ca51b1b8efd9
$ docker exec -it test-cvmfs-publisher-hs bash
[root@127ed5f4833f /]# systemctl status
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Both machines run docker 25.0.3 and containerd.io 1.6.28.

I cannot understand what's wrong with the new host; the only evident difference is the OS version, so maybe something related to the kernel (e.g. cgroups??) could be the culprit? Or could it be just me overlooking something?

Comment: grep for apparmor errors in the logs.

Comment: And using `systemd` to run `Apache` and `cron` in a docker container isn't an example of the best practice.

Comment: Apparmor unit is disabled, and anyway there's nothing in its logs. And I run systemd not for Apache and cron but for a service (CVMFS) which needs systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected it was an issue with cgroups, and in particular with cgroups v2. After adding:

```
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

to the kernel command line parameters to force cgroups v1 and rebooting everything works as expected. Effectively, it seems that Canonical switched to cgroups v2 in Ubuntu 21.10, so all of the above makes sense.